# Simple Keras Network in GradientTape: LookupError: No gradient defined for operation 'IteratorGetNext' (op type: IteratorGetNext)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tensorflow2.0

I've built a very simple TensorFlow Keras model with a single dense layer.  It works perfectly fine outside a `GradientTape` block, but inside a `GradientTape` block it raises `LookupError: No gradient defined for operation 'IteratorGetNext' (op type: IteratorGetNext)`

Code to reproduce:

```py
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

print(tf.__version__)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1, input_shape=(16,)))

fake_data = np.random.random((1, 16))

print(model.predict(fake_data).shape) # works
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    print(model.predict(fake_data).shape) # LookupError: No gradient defined for operation 'IteratorGetNext' (op type: IteratorGetNext)
```

This appears to work in TensorFlow 2.0.0, however it fails in TensorFlow 2.1.0 and 2.2.0

[Here](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/LryF/f72f8c7852cad04b11bf36ef16f2fadd/lookuperror.ipynb) is a notebook that replicates the issue.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

try to redefine the predict operation in GradientTape in this way

```
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    print(model(fake_data).shape)
```

Comment: Silly me, I should've spotted that.